# Can i use a mixture model for when I have an omitted variable?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, mixed-model, gaussian-mixture-distribution, generalized-additive-model, gamm4

I plan to fit a GAM or GAMM. There is one categorical variable which I think is important for explaining Y (or Y*), but it is not in my dataset - it is measurable but has not been measured.

Can I use a mixture model (GAMM) to compensate for the omission of this variable? If I had this variable, I would have just used a GAM.

Can you recommend some software for me to use? Do you have examples?
Is the gamm4 R package "the way to go"?

Other details: 
Y is count data, so I plan to use a Negative Binomial model or "family".
The purpose of this taks is to investigate the relationships between the variables.
Although the dataset, with N rows, fits into memory of my machine, a matrix with NxN rows will not fit into memory.

Comment: How would a mixture model deal with the problem illustrated by [Simpson's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) -- essentially a consequence of omitted variable bias?

Comment: @Glen_b I have not thought of a way how. I am starting to think that the short answer to this question is "no".